# Android 4.1.1 SSL Exception

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

We are having a problem related to ssl connection. The problem was the app cannot connect to the server using ssl connect after install it. But if kill the app and restart it, it worked. It only happens on android 4.1.1. Does anyone have the answer for this? Log listed below:

```
W/System.err(17335): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Error setting private key: ssl=0x52f6aae0: 
W/System.err(17335): error:140C10F7:SSL routines:SSL_SET_PKEY:unknown certificate type (external/openssl/ssl/ssl_rsa.c:189 0x40997bbc:0x00000000)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_use_OpenSSL_PrivateKey(Native Method)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.setCertificate(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:471)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.clientCertificateRequested(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:509)
06-17 17:02:03.682: W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
06-17 17:02:03.682: W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:651)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:435)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:592)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:510)
W/System.err(17335):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:488)
```

Thanks in advance.

Tao

EDIT: I have solved the problem by saving the certificate to local disk and reload it from local disk. Hope this help some one.